# Common Binary Relation that is not a partial order

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is an example of a common binary relation on a set A that would not be partially ordered? The most common binary relations I've seen are $=, <, \leq$, but all of these are partial orders.

Would simple multiplication produce a set that is not partially ordered?

i.e. Define $R: A \rightarrow B$ as $a \times b$ for $a \in A$ and $b \in B$

since $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ would be in $R$ and $a$ would not equal $b$.

Comment: Have you ever seen equivalence relations? Many of these aren't partial orders.

Comment: The only equivalence relation I've seen is =, but doesn't this produce a partially ordered set, since (a,b)

Comment: How about the relation in a directed (or undirected) graph which says there is an edge from one vertex to another? For graphs which contain cycles, this is not a partial order.

Comment: That one is both an equivalence relation and a partial order. If you can't find a 'natural' example, you're free to construct one. For instance the relation $\{(\ddot \smile,\ddot \frown), (\ddot \frown, \large {☺})\}$ isn't transitive.

Comment: The relation < which you have mentioned is not reflexive and therefore not a partial order.

Comment: You could use the relation $\neq$. 1 $\neq$ 3, 3 $\neq 1$, but obviously $1 = 1$. Are there other conditions (like reflexivity) that you want to satisfy? A relation is just a subset of some Cartesian product and you can define them arbitrarily. There probably aren't very many common ones that aren't partial orderings because they typically wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: @NickR Sometimes a partial order is defined as binary relation which is antireflexive and transitive.

Comment: While I'm mentioning graphs, you also of course have the other kind of graph - the subset of $A\times B$ for which $(a,b)$ belongs if and only if $f(a)=b$ for a function $f$. For most cases, this will not be a partial order.

Answer (score 1):

Define the relation $R$ over the real numbers where

$$
R = \{ (x,y) : |x - y| < 2 \}.
$$

This relation is reflexive and symmetric, but not transitive. For example, $(1,2) \in R$ and $(2,3) \in R$ but $(1,3) \not\in R$.